# My variable will not change in function

Tags: python, tkinter

My variable is not changing and I know it's not changing because "1" is printed to the console.
I'm trying to make the label increment when i press the button. However when I press the button, the variable stays at 1.
What am I doing wrong?
I've looked online for an answer but I cannot really find one that I can understand.

```
num = 0
import tkinter
box = tkinter.Tk()
v = tkinter.StringVar()
labels = tkinter.Label(box, textvariable = v)
labels.pack()

def numberz(num,v):
    num += 1
    v.set(num)
    print(num)

class MainWindow():
     box.title("My Stupid Program")
     buddon = tkinter.Button(box, text='PRESS ME', command = lambda:numberz(num,v))
     buddon.pack()

box.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please correct indentation for line `box.mainloop()`.

Comment: Function parameters are passed by value, not by reference, so assigning to it in the function doesn't change the caller's variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = 0
import tkinter
box = tkinter.Tk()
v = tkinter.StringVar()
labels = tkinter.Label(box, textvariable = v)
labels.pack()

def numberz(num,v):
    num += 1
    v.set(num)
    print(num)

class MainWindow():
     box.title("My Stupid Program")
     buddon = tkinter.Button(box, text='PRESS ME', command = lambda:numberz(num,v))
     buddon.pack()

box.mainloop()
```

You are changing the *parameter* `num` and not the *global* variable `num`

To change the *global* you need to specifically reference it. Notice how `num` is not passed in the `lambda` and now there is a `global num` in you function.

```
num = 0
import tkinter
box = tkinter.Tk()
v = tkinter.StringVar()
labels = tkinter.Label(box, textvariable = v)
labels.pack()

def numberz(v):
    global num
    num += 1
    v.set(num)
    print(num)

class MainWindow():
     box.title("My Stupid Program")
     buddon = tkinter.Button(box, text='PRESS ME', command = lambda:numberz(v))
     buddon.pack()

box.mainloop()
```

In any case, using globals should be restricted to very specific cases and not be of general use.